# Is it possible to have both get and set private in a public property?

Tags: c#

Is it theoretically possible to have both get and set private in a public property?
I'm not asking about whether it's good code. I got it marked wrong on a test by a professor who said it's an invalid property.

Comment: Lol no.. it's not possible.. Otherwise how can you access the property at all? What would be the point of it being public if it can't be accessed? It's a conflict of interest.. As such, you get a compiler error: `Cannot specify accessibility modifiers for both accessors of the property or indexer`

Comment: Remember what the `{ get; set; }` is shorthand for. It creates a private variable, with a get function and a set function. If both functions are private, nothing outside can see the variable at all, so its not a public property is it?

Comment: What's with the close votes? This is a perfectly valid question, it shouldn't be closed.

Comment: `Is it theoretically possible to have both get and set private in a public property?` What happened when you tried it?

Comment: It shows no research effort. At least writing it down and feeding it to the compiler is expected behaviour before coming here.

Comment: i typed it in visual studio and no errors appeared.

Answer (score 3):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/restricting-accessor-accessibility

> **Restrictions on Access Modifiers on Accessors Using the accessor
>   modifiers on properties or indexers is subject to these conditions:**
>
> - You cannot use accessor modifiers on an interface or an explicit
>     interface member implementation.
> - You can use accessor modifiers only if the property or indexer has
>     both set and get accessors. **In this case, the modifier is permitted on
>     one only of the two accessors.**
> - If the property or indexer has an override modifier, the accessor
>     modifier must match the accessor of the overridden accessor, if any.
> - The accessibility level on the accessor must be more restrictive than
>     the accessibility level on the property or indexer itself.

I have not tested it in Visual Studio, but using an online compiler it spits out the error (and highlights the faulty code):

> Cannot specify accessibility modifiers for both accessors of the
>   property or indexer: (insert property name here).

It makes sense. What would be the point of a "public" property that cannot be accessed publicly at all due to both the setter and getter being marked private. It's a conflict of interest.